# Firebase Admin SDK server (node.js) ignoring Firebase security rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have been trying to get my node.js server to listen to my firebase security rules, but it seems to ignore them every time. Below is my initialization code.  My service account is set up as an editor, and I even used `databaseAuthVariableOveride`.

```
var serviceAccount= require("./service-account.json");

    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
      databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
         uid: "my-service-account"
        }
    });
```

Below is a sample of my Firebase data.

```
    UserInputtedData:
       Region:
         locationID:
            $userSubmissionPushID:
                timeStamp: 1482037224063
                tag:0
```

My security rules are below.  I am trying to get my node server to only read the data under each `$userSubmissionPushID` if it was within the last hour based on my `timeStamp`. My rules work in the Firebase security simulator when I test it under different scenarios, but my server seems to simply ignore every rule, and read every child within `$locationID`.I even tried it without the rule `"auth.uid === 'my-service-account'`.

```
    "userInputtedData": {
        "Region": {
          "$locationID": {
            "$userSubmissionPushID": {
              ".read": "auth.uid === 'my-service-account' && data.child('timeStamp').val() > (now - 3600000)"
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

If anyone has any thoughts, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I should state that with the above security rules activated, no data is readable on the server.  It simply states starting up server, then remains blank.

Comment: You've only included a snippet of your rules, so its not clear whether or not you have a `.read` rule further up the rules hierarchy. If you do and have granted permission further up, that permission cannot be revoked.

Comment: I apologize.  I should have stated that, for development purposes, I have `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"`.  But when testing this new rule, I commented the `.read` rule out. So, I (should) have no confilcting rules, as that is the only other `.read` rule in my security rules.